# How to use OutputDebugString from Windows 8 C++ / WinRT Component

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, windows-8

I'm trying to write some debug info to the Visual Studio output window in a WinRT component.  I ran across the function [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx) which would appear to do what I want, however when I try to use it in my app I get "error 'OutputDebugString' identifier not found".  I'm new to C++, am I missing a "using namespace" or include?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to add:

```
 #include <..\um\debugapi.h>
```

Sample call:

```
App::App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Suspending += ref new SuspendingEventHandler(this, &App::OnSuspending);
    OutputDebugString(L"App initialized\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! For future reference, how can I figure out what include is needed for a given function call? I could not figure it out based on this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Just look at the SDK headers.

Comment: Also I'm not getting this on compile: error C1189: #error: "No Target Architecture"

Answer (score 4):

You need to add:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

As you can see in MSDN documentation, this is the header file in which this function is declared. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If all fails, try this at the top of your source file:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall OutputDebugStringA(const char *);
#define OutputDebugString OutputDebugStringA
```